# Evaluate $\int\limits_{-1/8}^{1/8}\arccos\left(x^2+5x\right)\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, inverse-function, trigonometric-integrals

> Find the value of $$\int\limits_{-1/8}^{1/8}\arccos\left(x^2+5x\right)\ dx$$

#### Answer given

> $\dfrac{\pi}{8}$

I used property and wrote the integral as $$\dfrac{1}{2}\int\limits_{-1/8}^{1/8} \left( \arccos\left(x^2+5x\right) + \arccos\left(x^2-5x\right) \right)\ dx$$, then added two inverse functions. But didn't prove to be useful. How should I do it?

Comment: What does "used property" mean?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur $$\int\limits_{-1/8}^{1/8}\arccos\left(x^2+5x\right)\ dx \equiv \int\limits_{-1/8}^{1/8}\arccos\left(x^2-5x\right)\ dx$$

Comment: Seeing what's returned by CAS, it looks gloomy (lots of ugly terms means there is marginal chance an adequate change of variable would make it nice). Basically it calls for $x^2+5x=\cos(u)$ but this doesn't lead anywhere.

Comment: Integration by parts leads to a result expressible in terms of elliptic integrals, although output from Mathematica is [incredibly messy](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%285+%2B+2+x%29*x%2Fsqrt%281+-+25+x%5E2+-+10+x%5E3+-+x%5E4%29) :(

Answer (score 2):

I've been wrong before but I'm not sure I buy the answer is $\pi/8$. Using the complementary angle formula, we have
$$
\int _{-1/8}^{1/8}\arccos(x^2+5x)\,dx = \int _{-1/8}^{1/8}\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin(x^2+5x)\,dx 
$$
$$
= \frac{\pi}{8}- \int _{-1/8}^{1/8}\arcsin(x^2+5x)\,dx 
$$But I don't think this last integral is $0$. The range is symmetric and $\arcsin$ is odd, but the argument isn't odd; it's slightly positive on $[-1/8,1/8]$ by a derivative argument. Numerical calculation suggests the answer isn't $\pi/8$ either.